# How to populate an input with query string value(s) using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have an input as below and I would like to prefill the value with the value of the query string so that when I access example.com/my.html?phone=12345 the value 1234 should be displayed in the input field. Sorry if my question seems stupid but I have no kind of experience with jquery and javascript

```
<input type="phone" value="" class="form-control" id="phonenumber"
placeholder="Phone number">
```

Comment: which server side language (php, jsp, asp) using?

Comment: Perhaps you could also do this on the server side?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this script:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

And for setting the values:

```
$("#phonenumber").val(getParameterByName("phone"));
```

**Reference:** [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

#### Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/hikoyaki/1?phone=12345

Comment: You can also loop through all the inputs in the form:

$('#someform input.form-control').each(function () {
            var name = $(this).attr('name');
            var val = getParameterByName(name);
            $('input[name="' + name + '"]').val(val);
        });

Comment: @Halceyon yep, possible.

Comment: It shows the code, but the query string is not updating any info.

Comment: @qjnr You need to know how JSBin works. There's a clear message. Please fork and try it out. `:)`

Comment: Oh, my bad! I didn't see it said 'Expired'! :P

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript `split()`

```
var test = 'example.com/my.html?phone=12345';
var res = test.split("=");
$("#phonenumber").val(res[1]);
```

> **Note:** Use this if you have only one query string in url.

Comment: in case `?name=test&phone=12345` ??

Comment: Yes @Girish this is for OP if he have only one query parameter `phone`

Comment: there can also `#` with 1 param, you should provide vital solution.

Comment: This solution is for OP only regarding `example.com/my.html?phone=12345` situation

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Plain javascript way of doing it

[CSS-TRICKS](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/)

```
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}
```

Comment: The question is clearly tagged with `jQuery` and NOT `JavaScript`.

Comment: if Javascript can do it then why bother with jquery ?

Answer (score -2):

Below example may help you

```
var location = 'example.com/my.html?phone=12345';
var phoneNo = location.split("?phone=")[1];
```

Comment: I guess the whole thing is about how to get it from the query string not from a string

Comment: there is no test variable in the solution given